# Virtualmin / Webmin - How to disable Virtualmin overriding the icons folder?

Tags: webmin, virtualmin

Virtualmin / Webmin is overriding my website icons folder, and displaying public domain icons https://www.webmin.com/icons/
(I am using Flutter for a PWA web app that has an icons folder)
How can I disable this override?